# How to get URL of the file stored on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

I have an app deployed on Heroku. Currently I need to write url of the hosted photo to send_invoice with that photo.

I checked that myPhoto.jpg is stored at https://myapp.herokuapp.com by running

```
~ $ heroku run bash
~ $ ls
```

Send_invoice works fine if using example `photo_url='http://erkelzaar.tsudao.com/models/perrotta/TIME_MACHINE.jpg'` but I need to send myPhoto.jpg

```
bot.send_invoice(message.chat.id, title='Working Time Machine',
                     description='Description',
                     provider_token=provider_token,
                     currency='usd',
                     photo_url='https://myapp.herokuapp.com/myPhoto.jpg',
                     photo_height=512,  # !=0/None or picture won't be shown
                     photo_width=512,
                     photo_size=512,
                     is_flexible=False,
                     prices=prices,
                     start_parameter='time-machine-example',
                     invoice_payload='HAPPY FRIDAYS COUPON')
```

I also tried

```
photo_url='file:///myPhoto.jpg'
```

The expected output should be

[image]
But I got

[image]
What I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: Which web framework do you use

Comment: I am not using web framework. Just python + pyTelegramBotAPI libs

Comment: Your `procfile` content

Comment: procfile: 
bot: python3 bot1.py

Comment: Pipfile:
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
pytelegrambotapi = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

Comment: Add flask framework; [Sample](https://github.com/SmartManoj/TelegramEchoBot/blob/master/telegram.py); Then add image to static folder